# Is the Heathrow expansion decision conditional upon private parties finding financing?

Tags: united-kingdom, infrastructure, financing

The UK House of Commons voted on approving Heathrow expansion, or at least, that's how it is described in the media.  At closer scrutiny, however, it looks like the vote is just about a government policy statement approving expansion in principle.  It is supposed to be privately funded (see also [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/31742/130)).

Does the vote relate to a a costed privately funded planning application?  Or can, in the event of parliamentary approval, Heathrow expansion still be cancelled or postponed if owners come back stating that they are unable to acquire the necessary financing?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the airport's private owner, Heathrow Airport Limited, will apply to the government's Planning Inspectorate for an unusual kind of national planning consent called a Development Consent Order.

From the airport company's official expansion website:

> Expansion will be authorised via a Development Consent Order, a special kind of consent for major infrastructure projects in England and Wales.

https://www.heathrowexpansion.com/the-expansion-plan/planning-process/